# Axios injecting 'localhost' in my pathname

Tags: javascript, axios

I am building out an axios request following their documentation.

I have a post:

```
const REFERRAL_API_URL= "https://referrals.gen.com"


export function createReferral() {
  axios({
    data: {},
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      ApiKey: ReferralApiKey,
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: `${REFERRAL_API_URL}/api/ReferralMasters`,
    withCredentials: true,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

When I call my function I get a 404 error saying:

```
NOT FOUND https://localhost:3000/referrals.gen.com/api/ReferralMasters
```

Why is `localhost:3000` being injected here?

Comment: are you sure your `REFERRAL_API_URL` has `https://` in it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it with next steps. Try creating api client with `axios.create()` like the following code suggests:

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: REFERRAL_API_URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        ApiKey: ReferralApiKey
    }
});
```

After you have such client send a request:

```
const config = {
    url,      // I suppose "ReferralMasters"
    method,   // "GET", "POST", "PUT" or "DELETE"
    data,     // custom body
    params    // object which key-values are respective to required parameters
};

const response = await apiClient.request(config);
```

For more custom configuration visit [axios docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api).